# How to copy "PILLOW image" type to use it in clipboard with transparency support in Python 3?

Tags: python, windows, image, python-imaging-library, clipboard

I have `PIL.Image.Image` type variable and I want to send it to the `Clipboard`, but I didn't figure out how to do it **without** saving as file temp file which I don't want to do,

I want to make all process in the **memory**, not save it as temp file then copy it again for SSD ,HDD lifespan optimization.

**Method 1:**
I tired use this code, but it doesn't support the alpha channel, it converted it to black as like this:
[alpha pixel turned to black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adq4F.jpg)

```py
    # image contain transparency PIL image

    output = BytesIO()
    image.convert("RGBA").save(output, "BMP")
    data = output.getvalue()[14:]   
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_DIB, data)
    output.close()
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```

**Method 2 :** it suggests save the image as `temp` file then copy it again, I didn't like this approach becouse it reduce the lifespan of HDD/SSD.

Comment: The code you tried converts the image to a bitmap (which doesn't support alpha channels) - what if you don't do that and just save the image directly as a PNG, e.g. `image.convert("RGBA").save(output, "PNG")`?

Comment: @wkl Hi ,thanks sadly  it makes the clipboard don't recognize the image and when paste it in paint.exe it shows this err `[can't complete operations ] information on the clipboard can't be inserted into paint
`

Comment: Microsoft Paint does not support transparency outside of the new preview version of Paint, so that may be part of the probelm (I don’t use Windows so I don’t know if that’s the problem).

Comment: @wkl yeah I used paint from windows 11 whitch support multi layer with transparency, i have tested on affinity photo and it Couse it a crash sadly.